# Changing kube-controller-manager.yaml with minkube

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, kubeadm, hpa

I want to add some flags to change sync periods. can I do it with minikube and kubectl? Or will I have to install and use kubeadm for any such kind of initialization? I refered the this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/control-plane-flags/).

I created and ran the yaml file but there was an error stating that

> error: unable to recognize "sync.yaml": no matches for kind "ClusterConfiguration" in version "kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2"

sync.yaml that I have used to change the flag (with minikube):

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.16.0
controllerManager:
  extraArgs:
    horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period: "60"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minikube and kubeadm are separate tools, but you can pass custom CLI options to minikube control plane components as detailed here https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/config/#modifying-kubernetes-defaults

```
minikube start --extra-config=controller-mananger.foo=bar
```

Comment: Thanks @coderanger for the quick response !
I stopped the minikube ran the following command and it worked .
minikube start --extra-config 'controller-manager.horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period=60s'